# Watin: file upload ...without file selection window?

Tags: file-upload, watin, browser-automation

with "file upload" HTML like this:

```
<input name="input_name" type="file" size="40" />
```

...there is no way for users to directly enter text into input area for security reasons, correct? file selection window pops up instead.

In Watin automation project, we are wanting to bypass the file selection window and place filename directly in text entry area - but we are not finding a way to do this.

How can this be accomplished? ...or perhaps it cannot be done due to the security constraints?

EDIT-- Not very promising according to this: 
[Programmatically set name of file to upload in webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997977/programmatically-set-name-of-file-to-upload-in-webpage)
Anyone have something to add?

Answer (score 0):

did you try to do that with javascript ? I mean with jQuery:

```
browser.Eval("$('input[name=\"input_name\"]').val('input_path')")
```

It is just an idea, I can't try on the computer I am.