# How to add files to html input (type file) programmatically via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, qunit

I am writing this code which requires me to do unit testing via Q-Unit. I have an input field where a user uploads a file and I then read it using "FileReader" of Javascript to do some processing on it. However, when writing unit-test, I am unable to upload the file on the input field so that I can unit test my function. What I am doing at the moment is as follows:

```
//Unit test bit
var done = assert.async();
var pngFile = new File([""],"../../img/test.jpg");
inputElement.files[0] = pngFile;
photoMosaic.extractImageFromInput(inputElement);
setTimeout(function() {
        assert.equal(photoMosaic.getImageName(),"../../img/test.jpg", "Correct file format test succeeds" );
        done();
    }, 500 );
```

The code in extractImageFromInput that extract the image is as follows:

```
//after some checkings and stuff
var reader = new FileReader();
                    // Closure to capture the file information.
                    reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
                        return function(e) {
                            // Render image
                            this.MainImage = document.createElement('IMG');
                            this.MainImage.src = e.target.result;
                            this.MainImage.setAttribute("name",theFile.name);
                            return this.MainImage;
                        };
                    })(file);
                    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

However, it gives me the following error:

```
GET data: net::ERR_INVALID_URL
```

I have tried putting the image in the same directory as the test and using just "test.jpg" as path but no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried an absolute URL (`http://www.yoursite.com/path/file.ext`)?

Comment: @ScottMarcus I did try that yes with no luck. Also another thing to notice is that I am using readAsDataURL. Perhaps that's breaking it?

Comment: Use `URL.createObjectURL(file)` instead of using the FileReader

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically set name of file to upload in webpage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/997977/programmatically-set-name-of-file-to-upload-in-webpage)